Receiving error "Binding element 'postData' implicitly has an 'any' type" in my Next14 typescript project
When I try to run yarn run build my NextJs-14 project, I get the error: Binding element 'postData' implicitly has an 'any' type. When I hover in post, it shows the postType but pastData has : any type and the same is the case when it is passed as prop.
          {posts.slice(1).map((post, idx) => (
            <FeatureCard key={idx} postData={post as postType} />
          ))}
        </div> 
My interface is :

interface postType {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    shortDescription: string;
    slug: string;
    image: string;
    publishedAt: string;
    body: string;
    author: Author;
    categories: Category[];
    content: string;

  } 

